# Testing form submit when enter key is pressed?

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I am trying to do some unit testing in PHP and based on the Symfony documentation, you test and submit based on the snippet below (Symfony v5.3 documentation)

```
$client = static::createClient();
$crawler = $client->request('GET', '/post/hello-world');

// select the button
$buttonCrawlerNode = $crawler->selectButton('submit');

// retrieve the Form object for the form belonging to this button
$form = $buttonCrawlerNode->form();

// set values on a form object
$form['my_form[name]'] = 'Fabien';
$form['my_form[subject]'] = 'Symfony rocks!';

// submit the Form object
$client->submit($form);
```

Any suggestions on how to mock the submission for a search bar that submits the when you press the enter or tab (for autocomplete) key?

EDIT:
Sample of what I currently have in the test case

```
//Test case for search bar

$client = static::createClient();

// path where the search bar is located
$crawler = $client->request('GET', '/user/search'); 

//Since there is no button, I used the hint text in the search bar
$buttonCrawlerNode = $crawler->selectButton('Search...');   

//When test is ran, this line gives a InvalidArgumentException: The current node list is empty.
$form = $buttonCrawlerNode->form(); 

$form['form_group[userSearchText]'] = "Fall Class schedule";
$client->submit($form);
$client->followRedirects();

//returns false -- Error 500
self::assertResponseIsSuccessful();
```

Comment: Submitting a form when hitting enter is either a browser feature or is implemented using JavaScript. In both cases the form should simply be submitted. So could simply select and submit the form as shown in your snipped. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @AndreiHerford Hi! Thank you for the input! I added a snippet of what I currently have. In the documentation, "selectButton('submit')" uses the value text of the button...in this case, I used the hint text. Is this the right way to go about this? Not even sure if I am implementing the code properly... Thank you for the help and patience!

Comment: Since there is no button, as I understand the javascript submits the form. So could try this https://symfony.com/doc/4.2/best_practices/tests.html#testing-javascript-functionality but I have no idea how easy is that. I would consider cypress for testing functionality with javascripts, I heard it is good.